# Extract information via COM with an ActiveX control

Tags: activex

I have a C# code that extracts information from another system via COM API and writes it to standard output. I want to run the same in a browser, so the users don't have to install the software.

Is it possible to write an ActiveX control that would start the other application, extract data and send them to the server?

How hard is it to convert a C# console application to ActiveX?

Is there any way to achieve the same browser-independent?

Recommendations?

Comment: This is exactly the wrong way to do it.  Running ActiveX/COM without registration requires a reg-free COM manifest.  They don't work in a browser.  Nor is a browser ever going to display what you write to stdout.  And the days of running ActiveX in a browser freely are over and done with.  Not in the least because only IE can support it and its not everybody's favorite browser.

Comment: And what is the right way of doing that? BTW, I don't need to send data to stdout, I need to send extracted data to the server.